# Verificar se existe item na array, se sim ignorar

Tags: php, lista

Tenho uma API que me retorna um JSON com uma lista de produtos
e possuo uma lista de produtos que quero verificar se existem na lista de produtos
Essa parte já consegui
Mas o que não estou conseguindo é fazer não verificar no caso de uma variação do produto
Exemplo
Tem 12345 na API
Mas na lista da API também existe 12345.1, 12345.2, 12345.3
Como faço para ignore no caso de encontrar a variação?
Pode pegar apenas a primeira

Meu código até então

```
 $response = array(
'12345.V1', '12345.V2', '12345.V3');
    $produtosaprocurar = array(
'12345');
    foreach ($response->getProducts() as $product) {
        for($i = 0; $i<count($produtosaprocurar); $i++) {
            $produtoaprocurar = $produtosaprocurar[$i];
            if($product->getQuantity() > 0) {
                if(strpos($product->getSellerSku(), $produtoaprocurar) !== false) {
                    echu($i.'-'.$product->getName());
                    echu('sku:'.$product->getSellerSku());
                    echu('price:'.$product->getPrice());
                    echu('quantity:'.$product->getQuantity());
                    $anuncios = file_get_html('https://www.dullsite.com.br/catalog/?q='.implode('+', explode(' ', $product->getName())).'&wtqs=1');
                // echo $anuncio;
                    if($anuncios->find('.main-list')) {
                        echu("Anuncio encontrado! Pesquisando vendedor...");
                        foreach($anuncios->find('.main-list .product-box') as $li) {
                            foreach($li->find('a') as $a) {
                                $anuncio = file_get_html($a->href);
                                foreach($anuncio->find(".product-seller-name strong") as $vendedor);
                                if($vendedor->innertext == 'an4l0g') {
                                    echu("Produto vendido por ".$vendedor->innertext);
                                    echu("Link do anúncio: ".$a->href);
                                    array_push($produtos, array(
                                        'sku' => $product->getSellerSku(),
                                        'title' => $product->getName(),
                                        "url" => $a->href
                                    ));
                                }
                                break; //pegar primeiro link
                            }

                        }
                    } else if($anuncios->find('.catalog-no-results-content')) {
                        echu("Esse produto não está ativo no site.");
                    }
                    $i++;
                    echu ('Encontrado!');
                    echu ($product->getSellerSku().'-'.$produtoaprocurar);
            // if($i == 149)
                // break;
                    unset($produtosaprocurar[$i]);
                    echo ('<hr/>');
                }
            }
        // }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Consegui utilizando

```
!in_array($produtoaprocurar, $produtosencontrados, TRUE);
```